# Integrate button leads to a 404 error popup step

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

When trying to install our application in the g suite marketplace, users face 404 error after approving the permissions https://www.screencast.com/t/C6tuwym8Sp.

when closing the popup we have another 2 step pop-up which doesn't lead anywhere, not calling the callback url. In the apps section in the g suite admin dashboard we can see that the application was integrated.

This behavior is breaking our flow as users are integrated in the g suite marketplace are out of sync in our backend.

Comment: opened a ticket also in google issue tracker, if you are facing the same problem please thumb up the in here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117367249

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed already, let me know if that's not the case.